# simplehtmldom usage with xampp

Tags: php, xampp, simple-html-dom

Hi fellow coders,
                 I am trying a new project in web scraping and have chosen simplehtmldom to do it with, I am using xampp to test the project on localhost. But I cant figure out where to put the extracted zip file of the simplehtmldom in the xampp folder. Is there a specific place to put it or should I just put it anywhere and give the address in the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your public folder structure. I think by default in Xampp it is htdocs.

If its just a simple script, put it in the same directory and do a require_once, for example:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
```

Alternatively you can put it in any folder you like and just include the path in your require.